# HTML or Javascript Component/Library for Virtual Treeview

Tags: javascript, html, treeview, components

**Can anyone recommend a virtual tree view GUI component/library for HTML5 & JavaScript?**

I'm not sure how well known the concept of a virtual tree view is. Essentially the idea is that the GUI component knows nothing of the actual data and only interacts with it via a set of functions as follows:

1. Returns the data object (e.g. some xml)
2. Is a function to get the children of the current node (this allows hiding some nodes in the xml)
3. A set of functions which extracts the text current node for each column (e.g. use an xml attribute to retrieve some data)

I hope this makes sense. Examples of Virtual Treeview's in other languages include:

http://www.infralution.com/virtualtree.html

http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview

Essentially I want to achieve similar functionality in  a web gui

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't meet your strange requirements, but I found this: http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview.html